# is there a way to add comments to proxy.config.json?

Tags: angular

Looking for a way to add comments to proxy.config.json.

I tried // as well as # but both result in an error when running ng serve.

```
"/uritocommentout*":{
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    },
```

Just want to commented out some of the mappings while in development

Comment: JSON does not support comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON should all be data, and if you include a comment, then it will be data too.

What you could do is start some fields with `_` and when you parse them, ignore them as comments. Like so:

```
{
    "_comment" : "This is a comment",
    "msg" : "This is data"
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for. The OP wants to "comment out" fields in the object not add a comment field.

Comment: Please read the first line of my answer. After the first line, all I do is make a suggestion.